# pandas add rows to multi-index at certain level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am attempting to get a reasonably performant solution to the following transformation on a dataframe:

given this dataframe:

[image]

produce:

[image]

i.e. padding a grouped level of a multi-index to a standardized length (number of rows)

Is there a reasonably fast way to do this on a somewhat large multi-index dataframe (~ several thousand columns and ~million rows)?

---

Here is the given dataframe dictionary for quick reference:

```
d = {'region': {0: 'intro',
  1: 'intro',
  2: 'intro',
  3: 'mid',
  4: 'mid',
  5: 'start',
  6: 'start',
  7: 'start',
  8: 'title',
  9: 'title'},
 'feat_index': {0: 9, 1: 3, 2: 0, 3: 7, 4: 8, 5: 2, 6: 4, 7: 1, 8: 6, 9: 5},
 'position_in_region': {0: 422,
  1: 5834,
  2: 8813,
  3: 3187,
  4: 9407,
  5: 997,
  6: 3154,
  7: 8416,
  8: 5408,
  9: 8421},
 'document_0': {0: 0.39,
  1: 0.79,
  2: 0.01,
  3: 0.55,
  4: 0.99,
  5: 0.67,
  6: 0.61,
  7: 0.84,
  8: 0.15,
  9: 0.23},
 'document_1': {0: 0.8,
  1: 0.06,
  2: 0.92,
  3: 0.74,
  4: 0.06,
  5: 0.96,
  6: 0.57,
  7: 0.19,
  8: 0.29,
  9: 0.24},
 'document_2': {0: 0.81,
  1: 0.15,
  2: 0.19,
  3: 0.17,
  4: 0.11,
  5: 0.34,
  6: 0.8,
  7: 0.03,
  8: 0.67,
  9: 0.46}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index(['region', 'feat_index', 'position_in_region'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` with left join by helper DataFrame created by [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
#get number of new rows by Counter.most_common(1)
from collections import Counter
no_vals = Counter(df.index.labels[0]).most_common(1)[0][1]
print(no_vals)
3

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'region':np.repeat(df.index.levels[0], no_vals),
                    'id':    np.tile(np.arange(no_vals), len(np.unique(df.index.labels[0])))})
print (df1)
   region  id
0   intro   0
1   intro   1
2   intro   2
3     mid   0
4     mid   1
5     mid   2
6   start   0
7   start   1
8   start   2
9   title   0
10  title   1
11  title   2
```

---

```
#MultiIndex to columns
df = df.reset_index()

#new could with counter of regions
df.insert(1, 'id', df.groupby('region').cumcount())
#merge, remove helper id columns and create MultiIndex
df = (df1.merge(df, how='left')
         .drop('id', 1)
         .set_index(['region', 'feat_index', 'position_in_region']))
print (df)
                                      document_0  document_1  document_2
region feat_index position_in_region                                    
intro  9.0        422.0                     0.39        0.80        0.81
       3.0        5834.0                    0.79        0.06        0.15
       0.0        8813.0                    0.01        0.92        0.19
mid    7.0        3187.0                    0.55        0.74        0.17
       8.0        9407.0                    0.99        0.06        0.11
       NaN        NaN                        NaN         NaN         NaN
start  2.0        997.0                     0.67        0.96        0.34
       4.0        3154.0                    0.61        0.57        0.80
       1.0        8416.0                    0.84        0.19        0.03
title  6.0        5408.0                    0.15        0.29        0.67
       5.0        8421.0                    0.23        0.24        0.46
       NaN        NaN                        NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
from collections import Counter
no_vals = Counter(df.index.labels[0]).most_common(1)[0][1]
print(no_vals)
3

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0],
                                  np.arange(no_vals)], names=['region','id'])
print (mux)
MultiIndex(levels=[['intro', 'mid', 'start', 'title'], [0, 1, 2]],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                  [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=['region', 'id'])

df = df.reset_index(level=[1, 2]).set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
df = (df.reindex(mux).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .set_index(['feat_index', 'position_in_region'], append=True))
print (df)
                                      document_0  document_1  document_2
region feat_index position_in_region                                    
intro  9.0        422.0                     0.39        0.80        0.81
       3.0        5834.0                    0.79        0.06        0.15
       0.0        8813.0                    0.01        0.92        0.19
mid    7.0        3187.0                    0.55        0.74        0.17
       8.0        9407.0                    0.99        0.06        0.11
       NaN        NaN                        NaN         NaN         NaN
start  2.0        997.0                     0.67        0.96        0.34
       4.0        3154.0                    0.61        0.57        0.80
       1.0        8416.0                    0.84        0.19        0.03
title  6.0        5408.0                    0.15        0.29        0.67
       5.0        8421.0                    0.23        0.24        0.46
       NaN        NaN                        NaN         NaN         NaN
```